# Title у определенной страницы WP

Tags: wordpress

Сайт имеет много зарегистрированных пользователей. Каждый из них имеет свой личный кабинет. Вот про эту страницу - Личный кабинет собственно вопрос.

URL страницы */account/?user=**ID***

**ID** - это, естественно, номер пользователя.

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы в тайтл записывалось, не как сейчас "Личный кабинет", а `display_name` того пользователя, чью страницу открывают. хозяина кабинета))

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (get_query_var('user')) {
    $user = get_userdata(get_query_var('user')); ?>
    <title>Личный кабинет <?php echo $user->display_name; ?> | <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
<?php } else { ?>
    <title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
<?php } ?>
```